# join with multiple table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using 3 tables to store the chat messages. The 1st table for task details, the 2d table for users list on the task and the last one for storing the chat messages.

I need the results like given below.

### my join code is below

```
$this->db->select('tm.task_number as taskno,tm.user_id as owner,tm.task_subject as subject,tm.task_mention_link as link,tm.task_module_key as key,ul.user_id as users,ul.task_users_type as type,tc.chat_id,tc.messages as msg,tc.chat_date_time as chat_time,tc.chat_updated as update,tc.deleted as deleted*');
$this->db->from("tasks_main as tm");
$this->db->join("tasks_users_list as ul","tm.task_number = ul.task_number","left");
$this->db->join("tasks_chat as tc","tc.task_number = ul.task_number",'right');
$this->db->where(array("tm.task_number"=>35,"ul.task_users_type<"=>3));
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
```

## Required Output is like this

```
**task details (separate array)**
taskno
owner
subject
link
key

**users (separate array)**
users list by users
7
2
3
4
9
**chat messages (separate array)**
msg list
ttt
ttttt
tttttt
ttttttt
ttttttttt
ttttttttt
```

## current details are:

[image for current details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s22h.png)

[image]

Comment: If you want three different arrays - here's a clue - generate 3 different arrays.

Comment: Instead of separating out the array, you can display the result as per your need while iterating in the view. I think that's the better choice.